Able to write the file to adls processed container from data bricks but unable to see the file in the adls container
I read the file from "adls" raw container and performed certain actions to check the null values renamed the columns and added an additional column to the file.
After all these actions I wrote the file to adls container. I used the read command back to check if the file was written successfully. The command has shown the values in the table, however, when I checked the adls container it says no file found.
Wondering how the same thing was correct in Databricks and can not find it in ADLS.
I have checked all the permissions and mounting parts.
I used Service Principal, azure key vault, created secret scope and connected adls to Databricks.
Permitted app registration and the adls account with the "Storage blob contributor" role under role assignments.
I was able to read the file and write the file successfully using data bricks. However, can not see the file in the adls container.

Please share the code you have tried. Are you using mount points or abfss:// ? Have you made sure you are checking the correct ADLS/container/directory? If using mount points, check which directory the mount point is pointing to.

Please share some sample data and the code you have tried.

you can use the below code to list all the files in the mount point
files = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/new_mount_point/")
for file in files:
    print(file.path)

dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d01/ dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/processed_data/

As you mentioned you are able read & write file using the mount script in databricks.
When writing to the putput to the ADLS
You can try the below approach:
output_path = "dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data"
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path)
files = dbutils.fs.ls(output_path)
if files:
    print(f"Files written to {output_path}:")
    for file in files:
        print(file.path)
else:
    print(f"No files found in {output_path}. Please check the output path and permissions.")

Results:
Files written to dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data:
dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data/_SUCCESS
dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data/_committed_2200847103700868366
dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data/_started_2200847103700868366
dbfs:/mnt/new_mount_point/d02/processed_data/part-00000-tid-2200847103700868366-a0c52993-d780-491a-a451-db0a3716efe0-24-1-c000.csv


